# What does this clause actually mean?

Tags: logic

Consider an instance of 2SAT that is given by the following clauses:
$\{\lnot x, y\}, \{\lnot y, z\}, \{\lnot z, w\}, \{\lnot w, u\lnot \},\{\lnot u, \lnot x\},\{x, \lnot u\}, \{u, \lnot w\}, \{w, \lnot z\}, \{z, \lnot y\}, \{y, x\}$.

What does $\{y,x\}$ actually say? Does it say $Y \wedge X$? Does it say $Y \vee X$? Does it say something completely different?

I'm just curious as to what this means, I manage to do the questions fine but would like a better understanding rather than just following along blindly.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are following the same notation as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability?wprov=sfla1) (I don't know if this is standard), then it means OR for terms in each pair and AND across all the pairs.

Comment: See [clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)).

Comment: if $\{a, b, c\}, \{c, d, e\}$ meant $(a \land b \land c) \lor (d \land e \land f)$, then SAT would be trivial to solve:  just pick any one clause and satisfy it's variables, and ignore the rest of the clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> A 2-SAT problem may be described using a Boolean expression with a special restricted form: a conjunction of disjunctions (and of ors), where each disjunction (or operation) has two arguments that may either be variables or the negations of variables.

So my guess would be your notation {¬x, y}, {¬y, z}, {¬z, w}, {¬w, u}{¬u, ¬x} {x, ¬u}, {u, ¬w}, {w, ¬z}, {z, ¬y}, {y, x} refers to

$$(¬x\lor y)\land (¬y\lor z)\land (¬z\lor w)\land (¬w\lor u) (¬u\lor ¬x)(x\lor ¬u)\land (u\lor ¬w)\land (w\lor ¬z)\land (z\lor ¬y)\land (y\lor x)$$